# Python flatten a dictionary column

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, parsing

It should be a simple line of code using pd.json_normalize function but it's working only with a single string and it's not batch processing my whole column

**Orginial dataframe**

[image]

```
df['addresses'][0]

[{'addressLine1': '124 Main Street',
  'addressLine2': '',
  'addressLine3': '',
  'city': 'Portland',
  'region': 'ME',
  'postalCode': '04019',
  'country': 'USA'}]
```

```
test = pd.json_normalize(result['addresses'][0])
test
```

[image]

Everything up to this point works, but when I use the function and apply to the whole column, the resulting dataframe turned out to look like this.

```
test = pd.json_normalize(result['addresses'])
test
```

[image]

Here are some column data:

```
[[{'addressLine1': '124 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '1234 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Chattanooga',
   'region': 'TN',
   'postalCode': '37402',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '1684151 Chair Street',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Notaplace',
   'region': 'AL',
   'postalCode': '48835',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '136 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '22118',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '123452 HoneyDo LN',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '123 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': 'Apt 2B',
   'addressLine3': 'Building B',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '123 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': 'Apt 2B',
   'addressLine3': 'Building B',
   'city': 'New York City',
   'region': 'NY',
   'postalCode': '10001',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '123 Main Street',
   'addressLine2': 'Apt 2B',
   'addressLine3': 'Building B',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '4578 Shiver Me Timbers Road',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'Portland',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}],
 [{'addressLine1': '124 Main ST',
   'addressLine2': '',
   'addressLine3': '',
   'city': 'PORTLAND',
   'region': 'ME',
   'postalCode': '04019',
   'country': 'USA'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can transform your dataframe `df` with `dict` data with following example:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('addresses').str[0].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  addressLine1 addressLine2 addressLine3           city region postalCode country
0              124 Main Street                                 Portland     ME      04019     USA
1             1234 Main Street                              Chattanooga     TN      37402     USA
2         1684151 Chair Street                                Notaplace     AL      48835     USA
3              136 Main Street                                 Portland     ME      22118     USA
4            123452 HoneyDo LN                                 Portland     ME      04019     USA
5              123 Main Street       Apt 2B   Building B       Portland     ME      04019     USA
6              123 Main Street       Apt 2B   Building B  New York City     NY      10001     USA
7              123 Main Street       Apt 2B   Building B       Portland     ME      04019     USA
8  4578 Shiver Me Timbers Road                                 Portland     ME      04019     USA
9                  124 Main ST                                 PORTLAND     ME      04019     USA
```

Comment: Actually the addresses is a column name in a dataframe, it's not actually a list. I was just providing more sample using a list. Do you know how to work directly within the dataframe?

Comment: @YoungZ Just call `out_df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('addresses').str[0].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)` with your dataframe `df` and in `out_df` you will have it flatenned.

Comment: this works, but I wouldn't use the `.str` accessors to work with lists. Although that is currently not raising an error, it is officially not supported, and may raise an error in the future

Answer (score 1):

It seems your list has one-element lists as elements.

Lets say your list is `address_list` then you get the first element in that list and then use `json_normalize`

```
pd.json_normalize([e[0] for e in address_list])
```

If the test data that you posted is actually a column then just use:

```
pd.json_normalize(result["addresses"].str[0])
```

Or if you have other columns in addition to `addresses` in your `result` dataframe:

```
pd.concat(
    [result.drop(column="addresses"), pd.json_normalize(result["addresses"].str[0])],
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: So it's not actually a list, 'addresses' is a column in the dataframe. Do you know how to work within the dataframe to flatten the column into multiple columns

Comment: it worked! but it removed all the column labels

Comment: Oh just remove `ignore_index=True` , because it is along `column` you wouldn't use it normally when it across `axis=1`. I updated the answer.